# How I can append jsonp array return by php

Tags: php, jquery, jsonp

I am having problem to access JSONP array that is return by php script, I am working for cross domain request.
My Code is  :

```
$('input#searchlocation').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://mydomain/searchlocation.php',
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        data: $('form#searchlocfrm').serialize(),
        processData: false,
        crossDomain: true,
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (data) {
            $("#searchlocation_result").html("");
            $.each(data.items, function (i, locdata) {
                console.log(locdata);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

PHP : Return array :

```
echo $_GET["callback"] . "(" . json_encode($res) . ")";
```

Please help me out how i can print return response into my page.
Thanks a ton in advance.

Comment: try `echo json_encode($res);`

Comment: `success` doesn't work with `dataType : jsonp`

Comment: @ValentinRusk It's jsonp, not json.

Comment: Hi diEcho, My call for webservice that will return response into json array, so please guide me how I can fetch return array via cross domain call.

Comment: Content type should be: "application/javascript"

Comment: Hi dfsq, Thank you for your help, its finally work with "application/javascript".

Comment: Thanks all for your quick help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to append `?callback=?` to your url, and use `.getJSON`

```
$('input#searchlocation').click(function () {
    $.getJSON('http://mydomain/searchlocation.php?callback=?', $('form#searchlocfrm').serialize(), function (data) {
        $("#searchlocation_result").html("");
        $.each(data.items, function (i, locdata) {
            console.log(locdata);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for your quick help

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input#searchlocation').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://mydomain/searchlocation.php',
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        data: $('form#searchlocfrm').serialize() + "callback=returnData",
        processData: false,
        crossDomain: true,
        contentType: "application/json"
    });
});

function returnData(data){
     $("#searchlocation_result").html("");
     $.each(data.items, function (i, locdata) {
            console.log(locdata);
     });
}
```

this should it be because its the idea with jsonp that you have a callback function and in the ajax there is no succes because it jsonp

Answer (score 0):

This should be enough:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://mydomain/searchlocation.php',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    data: $('form#searchlocfrm').serialize(),
    success: function (data) {
        // ...
    }
});
```

Also on server side:

```
header('Content-type: application/javascript');
echo $_GET["callback"] . "(" . json_encode($res) . ")";
```